# How to reshape a dataframe in a way that the first two columns form the name of a new column that takes values from yet another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
library("pageviews")
library("dplyr")

x = article_pageviews(project = "it.wikipedia", article = "ECB", platform = "all", user_type = "user", start = "2015100100", end = NULL, reformat = TRUE, granularity = "daily")
x = x %>% select(-project, -access, -agent, -granularity)

    language article       date     views
1       it     ECB      2015-10-01     2
```

What I would like to get is a dataframe like this:

```
    ECB.it   date
      2    2015-10-01
```

where the value of the column "views" goes into a new column "ECB.it" (`paste(x$article, x$language, sep = ".")`).

Can anyone help me do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the columns `article` and `language` into one and get the data in wide format.

```
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  unite(col, article, language, sep = '.') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = views)

#   date                ECB.it
#  <dttm>               <dbl>
#1 2015-10-01 00:00:00      2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transmute`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  transmute(ECB.it = views, date)
#  ECB.it       date
#1      2 2015-10-01
```